# Displaying number of unread messages in a navigation bar button

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

[image: Navigation Bar Buttons]

How to create this feature in which the no. of unread messages are displayed on top right of a navigation bar's button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That could just be a red view with a label added on top of a UINavigationBar.  For example, add this code and you'll notice something similar over the navigation bar:

```
UILabel *redLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
[redLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[redLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[redLabel setText:@"2"];
[redLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0]];
[redLabel setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[redLabel setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 1)];
[redLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];

[redLabel sizeToFit];
[redLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(120, 4, [redLabel frame].size.width + 6, [redLabel frame].size.height)];

[[[self navigationController] navigationBar] addSubview:redLabel];
```